# Converting a flat JSON Object to a Tree Data Structure

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, neo4j

I need to represent Neo4j nodes in a graph view using d3.js. However the output from Neo4j is a flat Json Structure as follows

```
Parent|Child
______|_____
A     |B
A     |C
A     |D
B     |E
B     |F
C     |G
D     |H
D     |I
```

However I need a Tree data structure in order to visualize the data using the `d3.js` Library.

How can i convert it to a structure as follows

```
 {
 "name": "A",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "B",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "E",
     "children": []
    },
    {
     "name": "F",
     "children": []
    }
   ]
  "name": "C",
  "children":[
      {
      "name":"G"
      "children":[]
      }
      ]
  }
```

and so on.....

Comment: If this data structure is required for your use in d3.js then it's more appropriate as a post-processing step in JavaScript. As far as I know, you cannot recursively nest maps in Neo4j because cannot do key assignments.

Comment: Yep but that is a hard process. The data set also huge and i cant get all at once.

Answer (score 2):

mkpchiran,

This isn't a total solution, but you can at least get part way there with a query of this form (assuming you have nodes linked by :CHILD_OF relationships):

```
MATCH (p)<-[:CHILD_OF]-(c)
WITH p, collect(c) AS cs
RETURN p, cs
```

This will give you the collection of children for each parent, so something along the lines of:

```
A, [B, C, D]
B, [E, F]
C, [G]
D, [H, I]
```

Hope this helps a bit.

Grace and peace,

Jim

Answer (score 1):

You can also check my [cy2neo](https://github.com/jexp/cy2neo) project which solved this in javascript, i.e. it uses the results from the cypher query with the `resultDataContents:graph` and renders them as d3-graph using alchemy.js